# Find last 2 values & calculate % change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, array

I need to calculate the percent change for the last 2 cells (months). The last 2 cells change monthly, with new data added.  I need the formula to find the last 2 cells--with value--in the row, and calculate the change.
I have tried the following formula with an output error #Value!

```
=(-INDEX(C48:O48,MATCH(TRUE,C48:O48<>0,0))+LOOKUP(2,1/(C48:O48>0),C48:O48))/INDEX(C48:O48, MATCH(TRUE,C48:O48<>0,0))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: =(-INDEX(C48:O48,MATCH(TRUE,C48:O48<>0,0))+LOOKUP(2,1/(C48:O48>0),C48:O48))/INDEX(C48:O48, MATCH(TRUE,C48:O48<>0,0))

Comment: with a #value output

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1699065/edit) to clarify it (not everyone will read all the comments) Some sample data and the expected output would also be useful

Comment: Have you tried to see if the various parts of your formula is working as intended? My eyeball test is failing to see how the formulas are taking just the last two cells (with a value) from your entire range selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is centered around using the [LET() function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) which is not supported in all version of Excel. You can do it without this function but the formula gets significantly longer it's much more difficult to understand.**

---

If your data doesn't have any gaps in it and we can count on the 2nd to last value being just to the left of the last value, the formula can be this:

```
=LET(monthRange,C48:O48,cBeg,MIN(COLUMN(monthRange)),cEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(monthRange<>""),COLUMN(monthRange)),lastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cEnd-cBeg+1),nextToLastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cEnd-cBeg),(lastValue-nextToLastValue)/nextToLastValue)
```

If you may have blanks and you don't want to study the difference between the second-to-last non-blank and the last non-blank, the formula gets a bit longer but it's the most robust solution:

```
=LET(monthRange,C48:O48,cBeg,MIN(COLUMN(monthRange)),cEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(monthRange<>""),COLUMN(monthRange)),allButLastRange,OFFSET(monthRange,0,0,1,cEnd-cBeg),cNextToEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(allButLastRange<>""),COLUMN(allButLastRange)),lastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cEnd-cBeg+1),nextToLastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cNextToEnd-cBeg+1),(lastValue-nextToLastValue)/nextToLastValue)
```

These seem like very daunting formulas but the beauty of LET() is that you can break them into chunks so it's much easier to understand. The format is `variable name, value` except that the very last term is just a `value` that gets returned. Taking the longer formula one piece at a time:

- `monthRange,C48:O48`

  - Defines `monthRange` to be the range we care about.
  - We could skip this entirely and reference the range directly but this 1) helps the rest of the formula be easier to read and 2) make the formula easier to update if the range we care about changes.
- `cBeg,MIN(COLUMN(monthRange))`

  - Find the first column in the range.
  - This is needed later in the INDEX() functions.
- `cEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(monthRange<>""),COLUMN(monthRange))`

  - Finds the column number of the last non-empty cell in the range.
  - Taken straight from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell).
- `allButLastRange,OFFSET(monthRange,0,0,1,cEnd-cBeg)`

  - Defines the range that starts where the first range starts and ends just to the left of the last value.
  - This isn't needed if you can count on the 2nd to last value always being just to the left of the last value.
- `cNextToEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(allButLastRange<>""),COLUMN(allButLastRange))`

  - Finds the column number of the last non-empty cell in that new, smaller range.
  - Again, this isn't needed unless you have blanks in your data.
- `lastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cEnd-cBeg+1)`

  - Extracts the value of the last data.
- `nextToLastValue,INDEX(monthRange,cNextToEnd-cBeg+1)`

  - Extracts the value of the 2nd to last data.
  - This is slightly different if you don't have blanks. `cNextToEnd-cBeg+1` becomes just `cEnd-cBeg`.
- `(lastValue-nextToLastValue)/nextToLastValue`

  - Does the math to return the % you want. You can change the terms in here depending on how you want the math to work.
  - I wrote it to be the % increase over the previous month.

---

If you don't care as much about readability or ease of update AND you know you won't have blanks in your data, you could make this much shorter:

```
=LET(cEnd,LOOKUP(2,1/(C48:O48<>""),COLUMN(C48:O48)),(INDEX(48:48,cEnd)-INDEX(48:48,cEnd-1))/INDEX(48:48,cEnd-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($C1:$AA1),$C1:$AA1)/LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($C1:$AA1),$B1:$Z1)-1
```

Note that `result_vector` is offset by one column in the second `LOOKUP` function in order to detect the penultimate entry.